# AWS performance for team in different location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

My company has taken one EC2 server for QA testing (we have QA team both in US and India) of my web application and given the URL `http://<ip_address>:<port>/myApp/` to access the web app.

As the server will be either in one of the country i.e. India or US.  If that's the case, it will be comparatively slow for one of the QA team or Amazon ensure somehow location does not matter?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you are planning to use your EC2 instances.

From a compute perspective, as long as all resources accessed are located in the AWS data center of your choice, there is no performance difference.

From a networking perspective, there will be higher delays when accessing your pages directly. Depending on your use case, you will notice delays, for example when navigating your page hosted abroad.

---

What you might want to take into account, is the availability of services besides EC2, since not all AWS services are available in all regions.[Region Table](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/) to check which service is available in which region.

Comment: what do you mean by `From a networking perspective, there will be higher delays when accessing your pages directly.` ?  2.  Then you said `From a compute perspective, as long as all resources accessed are located in the AWS data center of your choice, there is no performance difference` As we have taken only one EC2 server which lies in US datacenter.  So data center location is of mine choice. But i believe it will be bit slow for team in india because of more network hops. Is n't it ?